# What is the use of Proposition 1 (Section 6) or Rota (1964)?

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders, mobius-inversion

In the paper "On the Foundations of Combinatorial Theory
I. Theory of Miibius Functions" published in 1964, Gian Carlo Rota laid down te means for the widespread use of the Mobius inversion formula in combinatorics and lattice theory. 
I have a VERY specific question about this.
What are the applications of Proposition 1 of Section 6 and are there other proofs of it in texts?

Here follows the link to the paper (thanks to amrsa) : http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/rota1.pdf

Comment: Could you summarise the proposition for those of us without the paper?

Comment: "The zeta function on a locally finite partially ordered set is invertible in the incidence algebra."?

Comment: [link to the paper](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/rota1.pdf)

Comment: I am sorry, I amended the question. It was section 6, "The Euler Characteristics".